# Do section numbers differ between the C++11 standard and the gratis draft N3337?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

Does the numbering of clauses, sections, subsections, paragraphs, etc., differ between [the C++11 standard ISO/IEC 14882:2011](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS/ISO/IEC%2014882-2012) and [the later, gratis-downloadable draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3338.html) [N3337?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

To be clear:  my question is not whether it is advisable to use N3337 in place of the official standard, for that question [has already been well answered on Stackoverflow;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) but only whether the numbering differs.

For reference, [here is the most nearly relevant non-Stackoverflow answer](http://www.wilmott.com/textthread.cfm?catid=44&threadid=88823&FTVAR_MSGDBTABLE=) I find (if you follow the link, refer specifically to the item dated "Sun Mar 18, 12 06:41 PM").  Also for reference, @Nemo draws attention to a related Stackoverflow question with answers [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238958)

Comment: No, they don't. This is a comment and not an answer because I don't have the diff to prove it.

Comment: Finally! A stack overflow question with some research done behind it! +1

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238958/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

N3290, which is protected, is considered by the committee to be the final draft.  I have not purchased the ISO/IEC standard and compared them to ensure that it is identical to N3290.  I have also not heard any discussion on the committee questioning that it is identical.

I've compared the cross references of N3290 and N3337.  The cross references contain a complete list of the section.tags and section numbers.  They are identical except for two minor changes:

N3290 has:

```
unord.map.modifers 23.5.4.4
unord.multimap.modifers 23.5.5.3
```

N3337 has:

```
unord.map.modifiers 23.5.4.4
unord.multimap.modifiers 23.5.5.3
```

(modifers -> modifiers)

I do not know about paragraph numbers.  But [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3338.html) is a report from the editor concerning the changes made since the final draft.