# About binding a const reference to a sub-object of a temporary

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

With code like

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct P2d {
    double x, y;
    P2d(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    ~P2d() { printf("Destructor called\n"); }
};

P2d center() {
    return P2d(10, 10);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    const double& x = center().x;
    printf("x = %.18g\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

`g++` (version 5.2.0) will destroy the `P2d` temporary instance **before** entering the `printf` in `main`, but the value will be preserved anyway (i.e. instead of binding `x` to the actual member of the temporary `P2d` instance it will create **another temporary** `double` to copy the value of the member).

`clang++` (IMO correctly) instead extends the lifetime of the temporary `P2d` instance to the lifetime of the `x` reference and the destructor will be therefore called **after** the `printf` in `main`.

If instead of using plain `double` as type for the `x` and `y` members you make a class (e.g. `Double`) then both compilers agree and they extend the lifetime of the temporary `P2d` object to past the `printf`.

Is this a bug in `g++` or something allowed by the standard?

Comment: Tested this program on `gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0` on 2021-02-24 and it prints `x = 10, Destructor called`, so must be "fixed".  Will try MSVC too.

Comment: Tested with msvc `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.26.28805 for x64` on same date, and msvc incorrectly prints `Destructor called, x = 10` even with `/std:c++17`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is covered by [CWG 1651](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1651):

> The resolution of issues [616](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#616) and [1213](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1213), making the result of a member
>   access or subscript expression applied to a prvalue an xvalue, means
>   that binding a reference to such a subobject of a temporary does not
>   extend the temporary's lifetime. 12.2 [class.temporary] should be
>   revised to ensure that it does.

The status quo is that [only prvalues are treated as referring to temporaries](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/ecOwk4tzEWU/nEspcCcHEQAJ) - thus [[class.temporary]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#5) (*"The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary."*) is not considered applicable. Clang and GCC have not actually implemented issue 616's resolution, though. [`center().x` is treated as a prvalue by both](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc3471b082b51636). My best guess:

- GCC simply didn't react to any DRs yet, at all. It doesn't extend lifetime when using **scalar subobjects**, because those are **not** covered by [[dcl.init.ref]/(5.2.1.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5)<sup>†</sup>. So the complete temporary object doesn't need to live on (see [aschelper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35947797/3647361)), and it doesn't, because the reference doesn't bind directly. If the subobject is of class or array type, the reference binds directly, and GCC extends the temporary's lifetime. This has been noted in [DR 60297](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60297).
- Clang recognizes member access and implemented the "new" lifetime extension rules already - it even [handles casts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4cb98bb815d079d). Technically speaking, this is not consistent with the way it handles value categories. However, it is more sensible and will be the correct behavior once the aforementioned DR is resolved.

I'd therefore say that GCC is correct by current wording, but current wording is defective and vague, and Clang already implemented the pending resolution to DR 1651, which is [**N3918**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3918.html). This paper covers the example very clearly:

> If `E1` is a temporary expression and `E2` does not designate a
>   bit-field, then `E1.E2` is a temporary expression.

`center()` is a temporary expression as per the paper's wording for [expr.call]/11. Thus its modified wording in the aforementioned [class.temporary] /5 applies:

> The second context is when a reference does not bind directly (8.5.3
>   dcl.init.ref) **or is initialized with a temporary expression** (clause 5). **The corresponding temporary
>   object (if any) persists for the lifetime of the reference** except: *[...inapplicable exceptions...]*

Voilà, we have lifetime extension. Note that "the corresponding temporary object" is not clear enough, one of the reasons for the proposal's deferment; it will assuredly be adopted once it gets revised.

---

<sup>†</sup>

> is an xvalue (but not a bit-field), **class prvalue, array prvalue** or function lvalue and “`cv1 T1`” is reference-compatible with “`cv2 T2`”, or […]

Indeed, GCC respects this fully and will extend lifetime if the subobject has array type.

Comment: Is that wording going to get adopted? It's not in the latest working draft.

Comment: @Barry There are a few minor issues with the proposal as is; see the [discussion of CWG 1299](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1299). I'm very positive that a revised paper will be accepted. I'll message the author about it.

Comment: So the general remarks in 8.5.3 about reference initialization doesn't apply? `center()` is AFAIK a `prvalue` and I assume that a subobject of a `prvalue` is also a `prvalue`. Given that in the example is not a "class prvalue" seems to me the wording in 8.5.3 dictates the creation of a temporary `double` and binding to it instead of binding to the member subobject.

Comment: @6502 No, center().x is an xvalue.

Comment: @Columbo: where is it stated that `center().x` is an `xvalue`? The definition says "An xvalue is the result of certain kinds of expressions involving rvalue references". Where is the rvalue reference in this case?

Comment: @6502 Alright, your confusion is justified. I added the quote and an explanation for current wording. :-)

Comment: Changed again the accepted answer. The part "If E1 is an lvalue, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; otherwise E1.E2 is an xvalue" really makes it clear that `center().x` is an xvalue. However I can't avoid thinking what a mess of an already too much complicated semantic made the adoption of move semantic in C++11. I'm thinking this can be classified as C++ "jumping the shark" in the context of programming languages.

Comment: @Columbo Yeah, the normative definition of xvalue could use a lot of love. There's a note somewhere that actually details lots of cases, but why is it a note? Shrug.

Comment: @6502 I have done more research, and this appears to be more complicated than I thought. See my new answer.

Comment: In C++17 the references are [expr.ref]/4.2 "If `E1` is an lvalue, then `E1.E2` is an lvalue; otherwise `E1.E2` is an xvalue.", and [class.temporary]/6 covers that binding to `E1.E2` actually extends E1 in this circumstance

Comment: @M.M Yeah, so as I mentioned in my answer, the wording in N3918 has been adopted.

Answer (score 11):

I would argue for a bug in g++, because, quoting [draft N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), §12.2/5:

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is
>   bound or **the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound** persists for the lifetime of the reference except:

So its lifetime must be extended, except when:

> A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer [..]
>
> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call [..]
>
> The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement [..]
>
> A temporary bound to a reference in a `new-initializer` [..]

Our case doesn't fit any of these exceptions, thus it must follow the rule. I'd say g++ is wrong here.

Then, regarding the quote aschepler brought up from the same draft §8.5.3/5 (emphasis mine):

> A reference to type "*cv1* `T1`" is initialized by an expression of type "*cv2* `T2`" as follows:
>
> 1. If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
>    a. is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field) and "*cv1* `T1`" is reference-compatible with "*cv2* `T2`", or
>
>    b. has a class type ...
>
>    then ...
> 2. Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., *cv1* shall be `const`), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.
>
>    a. If the **initializer expression**
>
>    - i. **is an xvalue**, class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue and "*cv1* `T1`" is reference-compatible with "*cv2* `T2`", or
>    - ii. has a class type ...
>
>    **then the reference is bound to the value of the initializer expression in the first case**....
>
>    b. Otherwise, a temporary of type "*cv1* `T1`" is created and initialized from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference copy-initialization (8.5).  The reference is then bound to the temporary.

Looking at what an xvalue is, this time quoting http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category ...

> An xvalue ("expiring value") expression is [..]
>
> `a.m`, the member of object expression, where a is an rvalue and m is a non-static data member of non-reference type;

... the expression `center().x` **should be** an xvalue, thus case 2a from §8.5.3/5 applies (and **not** the copy). I'll stay with my suggestion: g++ is wrong.

Comment: In the table describing `xvalue` is stated that a function call returning a non-reference is a `prvalue`. So `center()` is a `prvalue` and, I assume, also `center().x` is a `prvalue`, not an `xvalue`. Apparently the intention is to relegate `xvalue`s only to move-construction cases...

Comment: I doubt that: `center()` is a prvalue, which is an rvalue. Moreover `x` is a non-static data member. Thus the part I quoted applies. Maybe this helps: The double returned from `2.0 + 2.0` is a temporary, but it has no "identity"; it's just the value. `center().x` is also a temporary double, but it *has* an identity, it's one of the double data members of `P2d`.

Comment: N3242 is ancient, why would you quote that

Comment: @M.M The question wasn't tagged with a specific standard, so I wanted to "keep it low" and stay with C++11 (which also introduced the concept of an xvalue, so)

Comment: N3242 is a pre-c++11 draft. The C++11 text is N3337 (free). [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10775520/1505939)

Comment: @M.M IIRC I just followed a link to "the latest publicity available working draft" on the committee's site. I bookmarked the newer document for future language lawyer fun, though :)

Comment: Preferably use C++14 draft (N4140) unless there's reason to use C++11 specifically; a lot of defects have been fixed since then

Comment: @6502 I just wanted to add: I was *right* all of the time! Even my explanation (in comments) was right. Sorry, but feels a lot better after pointing this out ;D

Comment: @DanielJour: That `g++` was in error was my first gut feeling and you can understand that from the question itself. However the point was describing exactly and clearly **why** it is a bug, citing or referring relevant parts of the standard haystack on where to find this specific needle.

Answer (score 5):

Just read [Columbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35947572/2069064).

---

This is a gcc bug. The relevant rule is in [[class.temporary]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#5):

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. [...]
>
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the **temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists
>   for the lifetime of the reference** except:
>   — A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion
>   of the full-expression containing the call.
>   — The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
>   extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.
>   — A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* (5.3.4) persists until the completion of the
>   full-expression containing the *new-initializer*.

We're binding a reference to a subobject of a temporary, so the temporary should persist for the lifetime of the reference. None of those three exceptions to this rule apply here.

Comment: But per 8.5.3, I believe the reference is not in fact bound to the subobject of the class temporary - see my answer.