# Differentiate an xvalue from an prvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

Given some expression `exp` I'd like to differentiate whether that expression results in an xvalue or an prvalue. In order to do so, I'd like to find a context in which evaluating the expression results in a compiler error if it's one of these value types, and compiles fine if it's the other.

Is there such a context that works ideally for fundamental, pod as well as non-pod types?

Alternatively a context which yields different results based on the value type would be sufficient, too.

Background: For [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35947513/1116364) I'd like to check whether an expression is an xvalue or not.

Comment: Use type traits to check if `decltype(exp)` is a reference.