# With a binded const& to a data member, why is the destructor being called early?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, destructor, move-semantics

According to this [blog](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/), the following code should be well defined:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{

  Foo()=default;
  Foo(Foo && f)=default;
  Foo(Foo const& f)=delete;
  ~Foo(){std::cout << __func__ << '\n';}

  //value to bind to
  int a=123;
};

int main(){

  const int& ptr = Foo{}.a;
  std::cout << ptr << '\n';
}
```

Although `Foo{}` creates a temporary, the binding with `const&` should prolong `Foo`'s lifetime.
The temporary should last as long as the reference.

The article states:

> Q3: When the reference goes out of scope, which destructor gets
>   called?
>   A3: The same destructor that would be called for the temporary
>   object. It’s just being delayed.

If that is the case, why does the program print:

```
~Foo
123
```

instead of:

```
123
~Foo
```

It seems that `Foo` is being destructed before I use the reference.

Comment: Lifetime extension only happens when a prvlaue (a "temporary object") is bound to a reference. You're not doing that. You would need to say `const Foo& ptr = Foo{};` to extend the lifetime.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: The temporary here is Foo{}, you're binding something else than that therefore no lifetime extension happens.

Comment: @Borgleader: Specifically, access of a non-constant data member of a prvalue produces an xvalue, not a prvalue. (This was only clarified in C++14. It was just kind of broken before.)

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Meh... sometimes simple observations don't really warrant an answer.

Comment: Section §12.2/5 from standard explains your doubts. More brief explentation can be found on H. Sutters blog: https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: What compiler are you using? [Clang](http://rextester.com/REJ5523) works well.

Comment: And see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226443/const-reference-to-member-of-temporary-object/38227096#comment63877160_38227096) if you're using GCC.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, they always do, if they answer the question. Comments are not subject to the peer review mechanisms.