# Lifetime extension of temporaries' data members and API design

Tags: c++, api-design, temporary, data-members

Suppose I have a cross-platform `Path` class like:

```
class Path {
public:
    // ...
    Path parent() const;                // e.g., /foo/bar -> /foo

    std::string const& as_utf8() const {
        return path;
    }
private:
    std::string path;
};
```

The `parent()` member function returns the parent path of `this` path, so it (rightly) returns a newly constructed `Path` object that represents it.

For a platform that represents paths at the OS-level as UTF-8 strings (e.g., Unix), it seems reasonable for `as_utf8()` to return a reference directly to the internal representation `path` since it's *already* UTF-8.

If I have code like:

```
std::string const &s = my_path.as_utf8();  // OK (as long as my_path exists)
// ...
Path const &parent = my_path.parent();     // OK (temporary lifetime extended)
```

Both these lines are fine because:

- Assuming `my_path` persists, then `s` remains valid.
- The lifetime of the temporary object returned by `parent()` is extended by the `const&`.

So far, so good. However, if I have code like:

```
std::string const &s = my_path.parent().as_utf8(); // WRONG
```

then this is *wrong* because the temporary object returned by `parent()` does *not* have its lifetime extended because the `const&` does *not* refer to the temporary but to a data member of it. At this point, if you try to use `s`, you'll either get garbage or a core dump. If the code were instead:

```
    std::string as_utf8() const {                 // Note: object and NOT const&
        return path;
    }
```

then the code would be correct.  However, it would be inefficient to create a temporary every time this member function is called.  The implication is also that *no* "getter" member functions should *ever* return references to their data members.

If the API is left as-is, then it would seem to place an undue burden on the caller to have to look at the return type of `as_utf8()` to see whether it returns a `const&` or not: if it does, then the caller *must* use an object and *not* a `const&`; if it returns an object, then the caller *may* use a `const&`.

So is there any way to solve this problem such that the API is both efficient in most cases yet prevents the user from obtaining dangling references from seemingly innocuous looking code?

---

By the way, this was compiled using g++ 5.3. It's possible that the lifetime of the temporary *should* be extended, but that the compiler has a bug.

Comment: *then this is wrong because the temporary object returned by parent() does not have its lifetime extended because the const& does not refer to the temporary but to a data member of it* this is wrong.  I am looking for the question that shows the lifetime is extended

Comment: @NathanOliver: What's wrong about what he said? He said that the temporary's lifetime is *not extended*. And it won't be.

Comment: @NathanOliver [citation needed]

Comment: @NicolBolas I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226443/const-reference-to-member-of-temporary-object) and its target state that a const reference to the member of a temporary is legal.

Comment: Just posted a new comment since I just missed the edit deadline

Comment: @NathanOliver But there's a difference between `temp().member` and `temp().get()` where `get()` happens to return `member`.

Comment: @aschepler I don't think so.  As long as `get` returns a reference to the member then you have the member as the reference is just an alias.

Comment: @NathanOliver: How could the compiler *possibly know* that `get` returns a reference to a member? All the compiler can see is that `get` returns a *reference*. No, temporary lifetime extension only happens when you get an NSDM, not call a member function.

Comment: @NathanOliver How will a compiler know to extend the lifetime of the temporary if `get` is not inline?

Comment: Okay so it is only if you take a reference to the member directly the compiler is allowed to extend the lifetime.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you could do is create 2 different versions of `as_utf8()`, one when used on lvalues, and one for rvalues. You would need C++11 though.

That way, you get the best of both worlds: a `const&` when the object isn't a temporary, and an efficient move when it isn't:

```
std::string const& as_utf8() const & {
                               // ^^^ Called from lvalues only
    return path;
}

std::string as_utf8() const && {
                        // ^^^^ Called from rvalues only
    return std::move(path); //We don't need path any more
}
```

Comment: What would you do if one of the platforms you had to support didn't have a C++11 compiler?

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas Well, it depends. I would use another platform to compile the code for the platform I had to support :) If this isn't possible, I would use the second version. Given that `path` isn't really long in most cases, the performance lost doesn't really matter in my opinion, as it is minimal :)

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas: I would stop worrying about trivial efficiency issues like this, and just return `std::string` by value.  Actually, unless the OP has evidence that those copies are expensive, that is what I would do anyway.

Comment: I would move `path` for rvalue to avoid the copy.

Comment: @Jarod42 Doesn't this "stop" the compiler from using RVO?

Comment: `path` is not a local variable, so NRVO doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Jarod42 Interesting :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To my mind the guiding principle as to whether to return a reference or an object is to examine the defined role of the originating class.

i.e. is the method exposing a simple property (argues for a reference, particularly if it's immutable), or is it *generating* something?

If it's generating a new object or representation we can reasonably expect it to return a distinct object.

Users of APIs are generally accustomed to understanding that properties do not outlive their host objects. This can of course be made plain in the documentation.

e.g.

```
struct path
{
    /// a property
    /// @note lifetime is no longer than the lifetime of this object
    std::string const& native() const;

    /// generate a new string representation in a different format
    std::string to_url() const;

};
```

I personally would avoid the prefix of `as_` in this case since to me it suggest that we're returning a new representation of the same object, such as:

```
struct world 
: std::enable_shared_from_this<world>
{
    struct sky {} my_sky_;

    /// returns a shared_ptr to my sky object, which shares its lifetime
    /// with this world.
    std::shared_ptr<sky> as_sky() 
    { 
      return std::shared_ptr<sky>(shared_from_this(), std::addressof(my_sky_));
    }
};
```