# What is the correct result of decltype( (A{}.int_member) )?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

Given the definition of type `A` :

```
struct A { int i; };
```

According to the specification *[expr.ref]* (I used *n4618*) :

> (if `E2` is non-reference,) ...If `E1` is an lvalue, then `E1.E2` is an lvalue; otherwise `E1.E2` is an *xvalue*...

obviously `A{}.i` is xvalue;
 also given that *[dcl.type.simple]* :

> (for `decltype(e)`,) — ... if `e` is an *unparenthesized* id-expression or an *unparenthesized* class member access...
>   — *otherwise*, if `e` is an *xvalue*, decltype(e) is *T&&*, where T is the type of `e`

therefore, `decltype( ( A{}.i ) )` shall yields *int&&*.

However I tried GCC5.1 and Clang3.9, they yield *int*, while vs2015u3 yields *int&&*. Which is correct?

Comment: Based on how I read it, I would agree with `int &&`

Comment: clang trunk [works as expected](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nGnizEVSZWcfSIau). n4618 is from the end of 2016, unlikely it's part of clang 3.9 and gcc 5.1.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, IMO `std::move(a)` is obviously an xvalue and thus the expression is obviously an xvalue too.

Comment: @skypjack I checked that the wordings I quoted are the same as in c++14 draft. Anyway, the clang trunk you gave works as draft-compliant.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's not a dup: the object expression is an xvalue in that question, but a prvalue here, so `move(a).m` has always been an xvalue but `A{}.int_member` has not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int&&` is correct.

The wording you cited in [expr.ref] was changed a couple years ago by [cwg 616](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#616), and wasn't immediately adopted by implementations; see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947296/about-binding-a-const-reference-to-a-sub-object-of-a-temporary/35947513). Basically, compilers had to adopt DR 616 and the paper on temporary expressions simultaneously, or they'd break code in which lifetime extension of an object, where we bind a reference to the object's *member*, is required. In the old model of implementations, only prvalues could designate objects for which lifetime extension is viable (although no such requirement existed in wording as pointed out by Johannes, it was vague wording before N3918, so…).

Comment: "only prvalues could designate objects for which lifetime extension is viable". I disagree, that seemed to be a common misconception, IIRC. The old model states: "The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference", it does not require that the subobject is expressed by a prvalue. Just that it is a subobject of a complete temporary object. Can you please clarify for me?

Comment: The linked answer states "The status quo is that only prvalues are treated as referring to temporaries" as a reason that the then-xvalue is not anymore lifetime extended: You seem to be stating that "Foo().bar" was a temporary at some time, by the fact that it was a prvalue, but that changing it to an xvalue made it a non-temporary. But I think that the spec does not support that. It said that "Foo()" is a temporary, and that, because we bind a subobject (which is not a temporary) of it to a reference, the temporary complete object is lifetime extended.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb IIRC [prvalue-ness was an implicit requirement that implementers followed](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-discussion/ecOwk4tzEWU/nEspcCcHEQAJ). I drafted this answer on the fly, anyway, but note that I never mentioned the wording, I only referred to what vendors did. I added a lil' note to make it clearer. Thanks for pointing this out, anyway!

Comment: I'm still unclear on how the problem was resolved in the standard... C++14 contains "otherwise E1.E2 is an xvalue..." but does not contain the words "temporary expression", so does that mean the C++14 text does not specify lifetime extension for binding to members? I also don't see the wording "temporary expression" in N4606.  Is C++17 going to adopt the "temporary expression" stuff, or is the problem going to be resolved in another way?

Comment: @M.M Always check the latest draft :)

Comment: OK, I see it is in N4618 (November 2016)