# Is a data member of a temporary object an xvalue in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, rvalue

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    vector<int> coll;
};

void f(const vector<int>&){}
void f(vector<int>&&){}

int main()
{
    f(A().coll); // Is "A().coll" an xvalue? 
}
```

**Does C++11 guarantee `f(A().coll)` will call `void f(vector<int>&&)`?**

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947296/about-binding-a-const-reference-to-a-sub-object-of-a-temporary

Comment: [GCC-compiled Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/z9lpCD) seems to feel that `coll` is an xvalue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. C++14 standard, §5.2.5/4.2, given `E1.E2`:

> If `E2` is a non-static data member and the type of `E1` is “*cq1 vq1 X*”, and the type of `E2` is “*cq2 vq2 T*”, the expression designates the named member of the object designated by the first expression. If `E1` is an lvalue, then `E1.E2` is an lvalue; **otherwise `E1.E2` is an xvalue.**

Pedantically, originally C++11 classified this as a prvalue, but such classification was meaningless so it was changed. If the change was applied by a defect report, though, then it's retroactive — the published C++11 standard document N3290 is wrong and the C++14 document defines C++11 instead. That's likely to be the case, as otherwise would require compilers to implement a subtle difference in behavior between `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14`. I'm lazy to search through DRs right now.

Comment: It was changed in 2013, see https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/728faf012696b81f906af77a1b22a8996dd7fa22 to resolve CWG616: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#616