# Value category of the subscript-expression on xvalue

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference, xvalue

From 5.2.1.1:

> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))` [...] except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.

However, with the code below:

```
struct S
{
    int arr[5];
};

int main()
{
    int &&r = S().arr[0];
}
```

both GCC and Clang complain about "rvalue reference cannot bind to lvalue int".

What have I misunderstood? As I understand `S()` is rvalue, `S().arr` is xvalue, so `S().arr[0]` should be xvalue as well and should be able to bind to rvalue refs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm pretty sure it does, cf. the `for(auto &&r : c)` pattern that also works for `std::vector<bool>`. Edit: [it does indeed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude rvalue references absolutely prolong lifetimes.

Comment: (rvalue) references prolong lifetimes, but only when a temporary *value* is assigned to them. In this case `arr[0]` returns a reference and the value is an array element, of an array which is a member variable of a temporary. So in this case `r` absolutely does dangle, just not  for the reasons originally mentioned. So OP: while this is a compiler bug, this code is still a terrible idea.

Comment: @NirFriedman No, `r` would prolong the lifetime of `S()`: "The temporary to which the reference is bound or the **temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound** persists for the lifetime of the reference"

Comment: @Barry No, you are incorrect. I don't know what else to say. Lifetime extension is not transitive. `S` is never assigned to a reference, so why would its lifetime be extended? Working example (had to change to const ref, because coliru's clang/gcc versions have the bug): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8f585b116449088.

Comment: @NirFriedman That's a bug. Actual [working example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/idgCoMX3idK9AsMw). `S`'s lifetime is extended because it's the complete object, per the text I cited.

Comment: @NirFriedman See [Columbo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35947572/2069064).

Comment: @Barry My apologies, I stand corrected. I think this is still a bit dicey though, as once you start binding references to references from temporaries it's still easy to get a dangle, e.g. `const auot& foo = *make_unique<Bar>();`, or I think (if I understand the wording), even replacing the array with a `vector`. In other words: I learned something new but I probably still won't have things like this in my code. I'd bind the temporary first and then access the member.

Comment: @Quentin (and others) you're right. But the example with a ranged-for loop is not a very good one since the lifetime of the container and its contained object would be longer than the loop anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the pattern I mentionned is useful in the case of containers whose iterators return proxy rvalues instead of references to actual contained object, as `std::vector<bool>` does. With `auto &&`, the proxies lifetime is correclty extended to the scope of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, for the reason you cite. `S().arr[0]` is an xvalue as of [DR 1213](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1213), so you should be able to bind an rvalue reference to it.

This is [gcc bug 79832](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79832). Note that clang HEAD compiles this [fine](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vrAAZEWxoeQvXoax).