# Why the different behaviors shown below between an lvalue and an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer

[clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a5e5ece938dd1aa) does not extend the lifetime of the temporary `S()` while initializing the const lvalue reference. But it does extend the lifetime of `S()` when initializing the rvalue reference. Why is that? If possible, I would like an answer with a quote from the Standard. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
struct B {
    B() { std::cout << "B()\n"; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B()\n"; }
};

struct S
{
    int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    B b;
    S() { std::cout << "S()\n"; }
    ~S() { std::cout << "~S()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    const int& r = S().a[0];

    B&& rr = S().b;

    std::cout << r << '\n';
    std::cout << "end of main\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
B()
S()
~S()
~B()
B()
S()
1
end of main
~S()
~B()
```

**EDIT** I have doubts about the accepted answer to the question, of which this is considered to be a dupe. And this is because, the two other answers mention explicitly that GCC has a bug on this topic. And I agree with those answers, simply because GCC doesn't compile `int &&r = S().a[0];` and it should, according to [[cass.temporary]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6).

**Besides this the OP said in his answer that GCC prints `~P extract`. Now it's printing `extract ~P`. So its clear to me this is a valid question.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947296/about-binding-a-const-reference-to-a-sub-object-of-a-temporary

Comment: FWIW g++ has the same behavior.

Comment: It has nothing to do with lvalue vs rvalue.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux As you can see in some of the answers GCC has a bug on this.

Comment: @NathanOliver If you change the const lvalue reference to an rvalue reference GCC doesn't compile. This is a bug in GCC. That's why I've chosen clang for this question.

Comment: Alexander seems to be correct. GCC is now printing `extract ~P()`, while the OP reported in the other question that it was printing `~P() extract`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 They are different questions. This one focus on why `S().a[0]` does not extend the lifetime. This is probably a Clang bug.

Comment: @xskxzr That's exactly what I mean. In [this other example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cc73ece3d6f6cc4) I think I show this more clearly. But [clang HEAD](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RKJ1nMbD4eOKxI6h) in the Wand box seems to do it right.