# Option to make signed integer overflow well defined in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473415/does-visual-c-consider-signed-integer-overflow-undefined) is a question that asks *whether* VC++ does consider it undefined, and [here: *Undefined behavior is closer than you think*](https://hownot2code.wordpress.com/2016/06/29/undefined-behavior-is-closer-than-you-think/) is a post that clearly shows that it *is* in fact undefined and the compiler/optimizer may mess up code in VS2015 no less.

What I haven't found so far is whether VC++ has any switch like [-fwrapv](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) of GCC to make the compiler/optimizer have signed overflow well defined. Is there any such option?

Comment: Even if there is such an option for VS, enabling it technically makes your language not C++ any more. The C++ standard explicitly (if in a roundabout way) says that signed integer overflow is undefined, if you want your code to be portable, even to other versions of the same compiler, you can't use extensions like that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - don't care whether it's "pure". If it can eliminate a source of bugs for a legacy codebase, I'm not shy to use it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - and with `-fwrapv` *of course* you can port to all versions of the compiler that also have this option and it will be perfectly defined, because the compiler docs say so.

Comment: MSVC seems to have a undocumented compiler flag `–d2UndefIntOverflow–`. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/new-code-optimizer/

Comment: @fujii - thanks. Very interesting link. This is only from VS2015 Update 3 upwards as far as I can tell. I gotta try that switch though :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check here at Microsoft's [Compiler Options Listed by Category](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx) there doesn't seem to be any such option.