# 0 < res <= (1 << 31) -1 - What does this mean?

Tags: bit-manipulation

This statement checks whether a number is 32 bits.

```
0 < res <= (1 << 31) -1
```

I can't seem to understand how, can someone help understand this bit shift syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does (1 << 31) >> 31 result in -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192284/why-does-1-31-31-result-in-1)

Comment: `1 << 31` creates 2^31 and `2^31 - 1` is the maximum positive 32-bit signed number.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This expression certainly does not check for a number being ***32*** bits, and would not work/compile at all in a significant number of languages. Which leads to @Bergi's question (beat my by 30 seconds), and perhaps the need for showing its context/origin.

Comment: @davidkonrad: How on earth is that a duplicate? It seems to be a different question entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, lets begin with an example:

1 in binary is 1

2 in binary is 10

4 in binary is 100

We can see that we need to 'add' a 0 at the end of each number to multiply it by 2 and in most languages we can do this with the following syntax: `number << 1`
Here we are saying that we add a 1 time a 0 to the left. `number >> 1` and here we add 1 time a 0 to the right.

So `1 << 31` means 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 ... 31 times which means 2^31 (so 32 bits)