# Why does texture index 31 is overridden in moderngl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, graphics, python-moderngl

I am writing a simple app that loads an image and displays it on the screen such that the left and right half are rendered separately.

```
import glm
import moderngl_window
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


class BugExample(moderngl_window.WindowConfig):
    LEFT_TEXTURE_IDX = 0 
    RIGHT_TEXTURE_IDX = 1 

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        image = Image.open("test.jpg").transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
        w, h = image.size
        w_even = 2 * (w // 2)
        left = image.crop((0, 0, w_even // 2, h))
        right = image.crop((w_even // 2, 0, w_even, h))
        self.texture_left = self.ctx.texture(left.size, 3, left.tobytes())
        self.texture_left.use(self.LEFT_TEXTURE_IDX)
        self.texture_right = self.ctx.texture(right.size, 3, right.tobytes())
        self.texture_right.use(self.RIGHT_TEXTURE_IDX)

        self.program = self.ctx.program(
            vertex_shader="""
                    #version 330
                    in vec2 in_position;
                    uniform mat4 model;
                    out vec2 uv0;
                    void main() {
                        gl_Position = model * vec4(in_position, 0.0, 1.0);
                        uv0 = (0.5 * in_position) + vec2(0.5);
                    }
                    """,
            fragment_shader="""
                    #version 330
                    out vec4 fragColor;
                    uniform sampler2D texture_idx;
                    in vec2 uv0;
                    void main() {
                        fragColor = texture(texture_idx, uv0);
                    }
                    """)
        self.left_scale_mat = glm.scale(glm.mat4(), glm.vec3(0.5, 1.0, 1.0))
        self.left_translate_mat = glm.translate(glm.mat4(), glm.vec3(-0.5, 0.0, 0.0))
        self.left_model_mat = self.left_translate_mat * self.left_scale_mat

        self.right_scale_mat = glm.scale(glm.mat4(), glm.vec3(0.5, 1.0, 1.0))
        self.right_translate_mat = glm.translate(glm.mat4(), glm.vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0))
        self.right_model_mat = self.right_translate_mat * self.right_scale_mat

        vertices = np.array([-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
                             -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype='f4')
        self.vbo = self.ctx.buffer(vertices)
        self.vao = self.ctx.simple_vertex_array(self.program, self.vbo, 'in_position')

    def render(self, time, frame_time):
        self.ctx.clear(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

        self.program["model"].write(bytes(self.left_model_mat))
        self.program["texture_idx"].value = self.LEFT_TEXTURE_IDX
        self.vao.render()

        self.program["model"].write(bytes(self.right_model_mat))
        self.program["texture_idx"].value = self.RIGHT_TEXTURE_IDX
        self.vao.render()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    moderngl_window.run_window_config(BugExample, args=('--window', 'glfw'))
```

Running this program will open a window with your image `test.jpg`.

***BUT*** something strange is happening at texture index 31:

If you change the indices such that the texture loaded **first** (the left texture in our case, as is described in the `render` method) has index 31, it will be overridden by the *other* texture, and you will see the right half repeated twice.

[image: example bug]

I should point out that if I had only one texture, and not two, and that texture had an index of `31`, there would have been no problem. The problem only arises when there is one texture with index `31` and another texture that is loaded *after* the `31` texture.

[EDIT: I should also point out that I have no problem loading *more than* 32 textures. If I was to separate my image into 32 tiles or more (instead of the 2 tiles in the example above), and even 64 tiles or more, the only problem will be with texture index `31` that will be overridden by the *last* texture loaded.]

I have a vague guess this has something to do with the way the number `31` is manipulated as an int? (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26192284/2934048))

**So, finally, my question is** - what is happening here?? Am I missing something larger that is happening, or is it just a fact of life and I should avoid texture index `31` and forget about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the internal implementation of [`Context.texture`](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/texture.html).

When a texture is loaded to the GPU, a texture object is generated and bound to a target and texture unit (except DSA). ModernGL seems to use texture unit 31 internally for this task.

I'm very sure about that, because when I print the active texture unit after `self.ctx.texture(left.size, 3, left.tobytes())`,

```py
from OpenGL.GL import *
```

```py
print(glGetInteger(GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE) - GL_TEXTURE0)
```

the output is 31, independent on the values of `LEFT_TEXTURE_IDX` and `RIGHT_TEXTURE_IDX`.

---

Explanation:

When you use the texture units 31 and 32:

> ```py
> LEFT_TEXTURE_IDX = 0 
> RIGHT_TEXTURE_IDX = 1
> ```

`textur_left` is loaded internally using texture unit 31:

> ```py
> self.texture_left = self.ctx.texture(left.size, 3, left.tobytes())
> ```

`textue_left` is explicitly bound to texture unit 31:

> ```py
> self.texture_left.use(self.LEFT_TEXTURE_IDX)
> ```

`texture_right` is loaded internally using texture unit 31. This breaks the binding of the `textue_left` to the texture unit 31:

> ```py
> self.texture_right = self.ctx.texture(right.size, 3, right.tobytes())
> ```

`texture_right` is explicitly bound to texture unit 32:

> ```py
> self.texture_right.use(self.RIGHT_TEXTURE_IDX)
> ```

Finally `texture_right` is bound to the texture units 31 and 32.

Change the order of the instructions to solve the issue. First load both textures and then assign them to texture units:

```py
self.texture_left = self.ctx.texture(left.size, 3, left.tobytes())
self.texture_right = self.ctx.texture(right.size, 3, right.tobytes())
self.texture_left.use(self.LEFT_TEXTURE_IDX)
self.texture_right.use(self.RIGHT_TEXTURE_IDX)
```

Comment: Wow this is super strange but surely solves the issue!
I was able to @work around@ the bug by moving the `use` statements from the `__init__` to the render method, `using` and then rendering each texture separately. Now I understand why this hack worked! thanks!